# wordpress contact form 7 to work with amp

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I do get following message when submitting Contact form 7

```
{"into": "#wpcf7-f1015-o1",
"status": "spam",
"message": "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later."}
```

The form works perfectly with Desktop view. But I created AMP page and wrote custom HTML code something like this.(Not the exact code due to security reasons) for the contact form for AMP since short code does not work.

```
<form action-xhr="<?= site_url();?>/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1015/feedback" method="post" target="_top" class="wpcf7-form ampform"  custom-validation-reporting="show-all-on-submit">

            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="1015">
            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.0.1">
            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f1015-o1">
            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0">

            <p><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit animated-btn-oppo"><span class="ajax-loader"></span></p></form>
```

Please help. Is this can be done using the FORM. Or is there any alternate solution for AMP.

Comment: did you get the Contact form 7 to work in AMP page?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write the custom code for creating the form using contact form 7 plugin.

You have to manage the form using with shortcode when you have generated by the contact form 7 plugin.

Go through with link for beginner - https://themeisle.com/blog/how-to-set-up-contact-form-7/

**OR**

you can write the code on custom page as like-

For Example:

Can I embed a contact form into my template file?
Yes, but you cannot insert a contact form shortcode into your template file directly. You will need to pass the code into do_shortcode() function and display its output like this:

Get more details, you can go through the link - https://contactform7.com/faq/